# javascript, best way to tell if a val is a single digit

Tags: javascript, regex, digits

whats the best way to tell if a value in javascript is a single digit.  Ive been doing something like

```
var valAsString = '' + val;
if (valAsString.match(/\d/) {}
```

clarification:  I mean one of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Also, should what I have work?  Im surprised how many different ways people are coming up with for this.

Comment: by single digit, you mean an integer between -10 and 10?

Comment: @russ, I mean what I said, any digit between 0-9.  Which is a subset of Z.

Comment: @russ, I realize I didn't make that clear up front -- sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `/\d/` regexp will match a digit anywhere on a string, for example in `"foo1"` will match `"1"`.

For a regexp approach need something like this, to ensure that the string will contain a single digit:

```
if (/^\d$/.test(val))  {
  //..
}
```

Note that I'm using the `test` method, which is recommended when you only want to check if a string matches the pattern, also, the `test` method internally will convert to sting the argument.

Another short non-regexp approach:

```
function isDigit(val) {
  return String(+val).charAt(0) == val;
}
```

Comment: @hvgotcodes, is doing type conversion to Number. It is basically ensuring that the `String` constructor gets a `Number` value as the argument. For example `typeof +'1' == 'number';`.  `+` in this example, is the [unary plus operator](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.4.6)

Answer (score 3):

Ummm, check if it's string length is equal to one?

```
if (typeof(val) === "number")
    {
    var valAsString = val.toString(10);
    if (valAsString.length === 1) {}
    }
```

This won't accept negative numbers or numbers with decimal components though.

Comment: If you look at the revisions you can see my previous code which was only 2 lines long if you were looking for less code. It did the same thing, it just incorporated the type check into the other `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to include negatives this will work, as will your solution.

```
var valAsString = val.toString();
if (valAsString.length === 1) {}
```

You could just check if the string is between -10 and 10 (assuming you want to include negatives). This will be fastest, but will not work for non-integers, so its probably best avoided.

If you do want to include negatives I'd probably check to see if the number is an integer then I'd go with something like this:

```
var isSingleDigitIncludingNegatives = function( arg ) {
    return ((typeof(myNum)=='number') && (myNum.toString().indexOf('.')==-1)) && (( -10 < arg ) && ( arg < 10))
```

Comment: Type conversion can make things complicated, e.g.: `isSingleDigit("\t\r\n    ") === true;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `val` is already numeric...

```
if ((val >= 0) && (val < 10) && (Math.floor(val) == val)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `val = "\t"` (ASCII 9) will cause it to identify as a number.

Comment: @Andrew: That's why I said *"assuming that `val` is already numeric"*. If `val` isn't a number then the tests would need to change. The OP wasn't clear on whether or not `val` was numeric.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var check = parseFloat(val);
var isSingleDigit = (!isNaN(check) && (check < 10 && check > -10) && check.toString().length ==1);
```

Comment: So is `1.23456` a single-digit number?

Comment: oh you are correct. Thank you. Edited based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below modification of your regular expression:

`valAsString.match(/^\d$/)`

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
(+val + val % 1 + 10) % 10 === val
```

should do it, assuming you only want to accept values of type `number`.

A cleaner solution is

```
typeof val === 'number' && val >>> 0 === val % 10
```

which can be easily adapted to include values of other types.